# Inconsistent use of backshifting in a reported speech paragraph

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

> Flow, he *argued,* **was** a state of mind, a level of concentration
> in which outside stimuli, even time itself, **seem** to fall away.
> But flow, he *added,* **cannot** be forced. <sup>[nytimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/10/27/science/mihaly-csikszentmihalyi-dead.html#:%7E:text=Flow%2C%20he%20argued)</sup>

The backshifting for general truths is optional.
If they went with the optional, a consistent paragraph would be:

> ... **is** ... **seem** ... **cannot** ...

Otherwise it would be:

> ... **was** ... **seemed** ... **could** not ...

Am I correct? I cannot understand the inconsistency in the original paragraph.

Comment: Yes, it is inconsistent. Presumably the writer used _was_ to correspond with _argued_, then drifted into the present tense because 'he' was talking about general truths.

Comment: Further to Kate Bunting's apt distinction, "...a level of concentration in which ... seem to fall away..." is either a direct quote without quotation marks to mark it as such, or the NYT author's paraphrase of something said which doesn't need to be backshifted as it is not so much reported speech as a clarification or elaboration of the reported assertion. Same is true of "cannot be forced".  The reported speech backshift is a kind of "wrapper" around those clauses.

Comment: @SouthIndianɪŋɡlɪʃɪfaɪd Yes, you are correct that it's inconsistent. Is really that your question, or do you want to know whether this inconsistency is acceptable or not?

Comment: I just wanted to verify that my understanding of reported speech was correct or not. Especially I was not sure the rule for relative clause (in which ...) where back shift should be applied or not.